# Trouble using flex-basis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm not sure if I'm not understanding the flexbox model correctly, or am using it incorrectly.

I have a simple enough repeated HTML block:

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">Label:</span>
    <span class="value">{{session.value}}</span>
</div>
```

What I was aiming to do was have every label be the same width, and have the value take up the remaining space. Usually, I'd go with something like a float or some trickery, but I decided to try flexbox instead.

The CSS I tried is simple:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.label {
    width: 150px;
    flex-basis: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I also tried `flex-basis: 150px`. Unfortunately, what's happening is while I am getting a single row when the content in value is multi-line, label squeezes into the minimum space available. I was under the impression that adding `flex-basis` set that flex container at a width and then other containers fit the space remaining, based on their flex grow/shrinks? Am I not understanding flexbox or not using it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flex items with flex direction `row` (the default), you use `flex-basis` instead of `width`, when to defined a fixed width.

So for the `.label` that will be

```
.label {
    flex-basis: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now, for the `.value` to take the remaining space you use `flex-grow`, and since the default is `0`, and by giving the `.value` a `1`, the `.value` will take 1 part of the remaining space and the `.label` 0 part, hence the `.value` will fill the rest.

```
.value {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

In case of lack of space, the 3rd property, `flex-shrink`, which defaults to `1`, will then allow the `.label` to shrink.

Stack snippet

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.label {
  flex-basis: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.value {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* styling for this demo */
.row > span {
  border: 1px dotted lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="label">Label:</span>
  <span class="value">{{session.value}}</span>
</div>
```

---

If you don't want to allow the `.label` to shrink beyond its `flex-basis`, set its `flex-shrink` to `0`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.label {
  flex-basis: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.value {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* styling for this demo */
.row > span {
  border: 1px dotted lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="label">Label:</span>
  <span class="value">{{session.value}}</span>
</div>
```

---

The 2nd sample using the shorthand version `flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.label {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.value {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

/* styling for this demo */
.row > span {
  border: 1px dotted lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="label">Label:</span>
  <span class="value">{{session.value}}</span>
</div>
```

---

Here is a great article how to use Flexbox. It covers also prefixed properties and the "old", "tweener", and "new" versions.

- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I actually am using that guide, but I didn't realize I should explicitly adding flex-shrink to 0 was the key. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Set [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) and [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) to `0`, and [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) to `150px` for the label.
2. Set [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) and [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) to `1`, and [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) to `100%` for the value.
3. Use shorthand [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property.

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.label {
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.value {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">Label 1:</span>
    <span class="value">{{session.value1}}</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">Label 2:</span>
    <span class="value">{{session.value2}}</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">Label 3:</span>
    <span class="value">{{session.value3}}</span>
</div>
```

Note that `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-shink: 1` are the default values for most browsers and you could use only `flex-basis` property, but some old browsers have some nuances, [for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink#Browser_compatibility):

> Internet Explorer 10 uses `0` instead of `1` as the initial value for the `flex-shrink` property. A workaround is to always set an explicit value for `flex-shrink`.

That's why I prefer using explicit values for [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property.